# License Compatibility: CC-BY-NC 3.0 with GPL2 (for Wordpress)?

Tags: licensing, gpl, creative-commons

I'm trying to figure out if I can use code licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial 3.0 (CC-BY-NC 3.0) in a Wordpress plugin (which must be released under GPL).  I *think* the answer is "no," based on here (https://www.gnu.org/licenses/license-list.en.html#CC-BY-NC), but I find the whole licensing mess to be just incomprehensible.

Basically, I already have a plugin that uses Fancybox (http://fancybox.net/).  Prior to v2.0 this was licensed under GPL; unfortunately, the author decided to release v2.0+ under CC-BY-NC (http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#license).  1.x is now extremely outdated and is having some problems with newer releases of WP.

So what I'm trying to figure out is, can I update the copy of Fancybox that I'm bundling with my plugin to 2.0?  I think the answer is "no," because the author changed its license to CC-BY-NC. But I just want to make sure, before I start spinning my wheels and looking for a totally new solution...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CC-BY-NC is not a free or open source license, because it lacks one fundamental freedom: to use the work for *any* purpose (See the [OSI Open Source Definition](http://opensource.org/docs/osd) under “No Discrimination Against Fields of Endeavor” and the [FSF Free Software Definition](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)). The restriction to only use the work for non-commertial purposes is incompatible with free software. Also, the CC licenses aren't really suited for licensing source code, and even the non-NC variants (e.g. CC-BY-SA) might be incompatible with the GPL.

So, you're out of luck. Of course, the original Fancybox will still be GPL-licensed, as are any third-party modifications – only the original author can re-license their work. You could therefore try to fix the issues yourself, or look around for a fork someone else started.

Comment: Damn, that's what I thought :(  Thanks for the super-clear answer though! :)